# Given 2 of 3 vertices that define a tetrahedron and all 3 angles between them, find 3rd vertex

Tags: algorithm, 3d, geometry

Suppose one of a tetrahedron's four vertices is at the origin and the other three are at the end of vectors **u**, **v**, and **w**. If vectors **u** and **v** are known, and the angles between **u** and **v**, **v** and **w**, and **w** and **u** are also known, it seems there is a closed form solution for **w**: the intersection of the two cones formed by rotating a vector at the **u** and **w** angle about the **u** axis, and by rotating a vector at the **v** and **w** angle about the **v** axis.

Although I haven't been able to come up with a closed form solution in a couple days, I'm hoping it is due to my lack of experience with 3d geometry and that someone with more experience might have a helpful suggestion.

Comment: Would this be better posted to math.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are not enough data to calculate vertice w position. But it is possible to find unit vector **w** (if it exists). Just use scalar product properties and solve equation system
(I've used (vx,vy,vz) as components of unit (normalized) vector **v**)

```
vx*wx+vy*wy+vz*wz=Cos(v,w angle)
ux*wx+uy*wy+uz*wz=Cos(u,w angle)
wx^2+wy^2+wz^2=1  //unit vector
```

This system can give us: no solutions (cones don't overlap); one solution (cones touching); two solutions (two rays as cones' surfaces intersection)

Comment: Thank you. Adding the unit vector constraint is okay in the problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and found MBo's answer very useful. But I think we can say a bit more about the value of **w**, because we're free to pick the coordinate system to work in. In particular, if we choose the x-axis to be in the direction of **u**, and the xy-plane to contain the vector **v**, then MBo's system of equations becomes:

```
   wx         = cos(uw)
vx*wx + vy*wy = cos(vw)
||w||         = 1
```

and this coordinate system gives

```
vx = cos(uv), vy = sin(uv)
```

so immediately we get that

```
                                                   _____________________
    (           cos(vw) - cos(uv) * cos(uw)    +  /        2              )
w = ( cos(uw), ----------------------------- , - /  1 - cos (uw) - wy*wy  )
    (                     sin(uv)              \/                         )
```

The +- on the square root gives the two possible solutions, unless of course `1 - cos^2(uw) - wy^2 <= 0`. The division by `sin(uv)` also highlights a degenerate case when **u** and **v** are linearly dependent (point in the same direction).

Another check we can make is that if the vectors `u` and `v` are orthogonal, it's known that  `wy = cos(vw)` (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/726782/find-a-3d-vector-given-the-angles-of-the-axes-and-a-magnitude). This is what falls out of the expression above (because `cos(uv) = 0` and `sin(uv) = 1`).